# How to create a public query database using Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have been working on Data Science for last three years, this is the first time that I am working on a public database project as I don't have any previous web development experience. I want to create a simple data base which holds  a list of countries:

like this;

```
Table-1. 

S. No. Country 
1      Argentina 
2      Bangladesh 
3      Canada 
4      India 
5      Pakistan
```

Now each country having some data that can be explore via clicking on a particular country name,

```
Table-2 

S. No.  OutBreak    Year    Strains      PMID 

1          1          1935  O1/O131     123465
2          3          1996    O1        455465
3          5          2012   O131       238475
```

I have a very basic knowledge of MySQL and want to pursue  this project using Django, what would be the best tutorial or a way that I can follow? I have search lots of tutorial on YouTube and other sources but most of them dealt with blog creation or social networking.

Please give a suggestion how can I go with Django for this particular Task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to start with the official Django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/).
And instead of the Question model, you make it Country model, and instead of Choice model you can make your CountryDiseases model.
short ex:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class CountryDiseases(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    outbreak = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="OutBreak")
    year = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    strains = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    pmid = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name="PMID")
```

Also you can use Django IDE's, like PyCharm, PyDev and many others.
Goodluck

Comment: Thanks for your answer its helpful. We have used "CharField" three times but why did we  set "verbose_name" only for "PMID" ?